# Cron job doesn't work

Tags: cron, crontab

I have a couple cron jobs in my module

The problem is that the Magento cron doesn't run one of them, but runs the another one. I have already installed AoeScheduler and that allows to me to run these jobs manually. When I do that both of them run well.

So the only problem is when it runs through `cron.php` or `cron sh`. Also I can see that there's no new row on `cron_shedule` tab about this job.

This is my cron configuration y config.xml

```
        <validoc_bulksync_import_exigoprofile>
            <run><model>validoc_exigobulksync/cron::processImportProfile</model></run>
        </validoc_bulksync_import_exigoprofile>
        <validoc_bulksync_import_exigoitem>
            <run><model>validoc_exigobulksync/cron::processImportJobs</model></run>
        </validoc_bulksync_import_exigoitem>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Im using a model class to suply the needed configuration for those jobs, just like i'd working with cron_path.

> Validoc_Exigobulksync_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Backend_Exigobulksync_Cron extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
>   {
>   const CRON_STRING_PATH = 'crontab/jobs/validoc_bulksync_import_exigoprofile>/schedule/cron_expr';
>
> const CRON_STRING_PATH2 = 'crontab/jobs/validoc_bulksync_import_exigoitem/schedule/cron_expr';
>
> protected function _afterSave()
>   {
>   $minute1 = $this->getData('groups/sheduleprofile/fields/minute/value');
>   $hour1 = $this->getData('groups/sheduleprofile/fields/hour/value');
>   $minute2 = $this->getData('groups/sheduleimport/fields/minute/value');
>   $hour2 = $this->getData('groups/sheduleimport/fields/hour/value');
>
> $frequencyDaily = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency::CRON_DAILY;
>   $frequencyWeekly = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency::CRON_WEEKLY;
>   $frequencyMonthly = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency::CRON_MONTHLY;
>
> $cronDayOfWeek = date('N');
>
> $cronExprArray = array(
>   $minute1,                                   # Minute
>   $hour1,                                   # Hour
>   (frequency == $frequencyMonthly) ? '1' : '*',       # Day of the Month
>   '*',                                                # Month of the Year
>   (frequency == $frequencyWeekly) ? '1' : '*',        # Day of the Week
>   );
>     $cronExprArray2 = array(
>        $minute2,                                   # Minute
>       $hour2,                                   # Hour
>      (frequency == $frequencyMonthly) ? '1' : '*',       # Day of the Month
>          '*',                                                # Month of the Year
>          (frequency == $frequencyWeekly) ? '1' : '*',        # Day of the Week
>     );
>
> $cronExprString = join(' ', $cronExprArray);
>   $cronExprString2 = join(' ', $cronExprArray2);
>   try {
>   Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
>   ->load(self::CRON_STRING_PATH, 'path')
>   ->setValue($cronExprString)
>   ->setPath(self::CRON_STRING_PATH)
>   ->save();
>   }
>   catch (Exception $e) {
>   throw new Exception(Mage::helper('cron')->__('Unable to save the cron expression.'));
>
> }
>      try {
>         Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
>            ->load(self::CRON_STRING_PATH2, 'path')
>           ->setValue($cronExprString2)
>          ->setPath(self::CRON_STRING_PATH2)
>         ->save();
>   }
>   catch (Exception $e) {
>     throw new Exception(Mage::helper('cron')->__('Unable to save the cron expression.'));

```
}
```

> }
>   }

Comment: Can you show us the cron configuration in the config.xml for both?

Comment: i've edited my post, that's my configuration. the first one, is the one that doesn't work, both of them are configured in same way.

Comment: note: i have run this cron jobs y another thre sites and in all of then those work perfectly

Comment: Without a cron_expr or config_path node in your declaration, neither of these jobs can be run automatically as the Magento system does not know when to run them.

Comment: I've edited my post, sorry, this is my first time using this question system, there is the reason why i didn't use the cron_expr, and i said before, this same script, is working in another thre enviroments.

Answer (score 2):

Although you defined the model to run you didn't specify a schedule per task.

```
 <jobs>
        <validoc_bulksync_import_exigoprofile>
            <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>validoc_exigobulksync/cron::processImportProfile</model></run>
        </validoc_bulksync_import_exigoprofile>
        <validoc_bulksync_import_exigoitem>
            <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>validoc_exigobulksync/cron::processImportJobs</model></run>
        </validoc_bulksync_import_exigoitem>
    </jobs>
```

The schedule consists of several moment indicators

```
* * * * * 
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

Also make sure your server is running a Linux cronjob for `cron.php`

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/magento/cron.php
```

And check the Apache and Magento logging for any possible errors. If one cronjob fails all that come after that will fail too.

Comment: Thanks for answer, maybe a did'n explain well, but i have the cron tab runing in magento, and it's runing all jobs, except, the first one of these jobs y my module, i didn't use the kind of configuracion of cron cus im usin system store values.

Comment: And when you run the task trough Aoe_Scheduler it does work? Do you run it directly or do you schedule it? Did you try and contact the module developer?

Comment: Yes, when i run the task trough Aoe_Sheduler it runs awsome, the worst is that i have another thre enviroments, stage, dev and my own local, and in these ones, all goes perfectly.

Comment: Sounds like it gives an error somewhere or fails in some condition. Thats the only reason I can think of, specially if it runs on other locations

Comment: well, im really confused, because is the same code in all locations, im using the same repository for all of them.

Comment: Without any more info it's gonna be pretty hard to help you out here. Sorry